# Need to throw event to Nest server when column is updated in SQL Server table

Tags: node.js, sql-server, websocket, nestjs

I need to throw event to my Nest js whenever a column (`stat_name`) in my table (`bfr_live_sessions`) is updated.

I have created websocket gateway with this code:

```
// src/websocket.gateway.ts
import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class WebsocketGateway {
  private server: Server;

  @WebSocketServer() setServer(server: Server) {
    this.server = server;
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('statusUpdate')
  handleStatusUpdate(payload: any): void {
    if (this.server) {
      this.server.emit('statusUpdate', payload);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `websocket.module` file:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WebsocketGateway } from './websocket.gateway';

@Module({
  providers: [WebsocketGateway],
})
export class WebsocketModule {}
```

Below is my entity :

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity("bfr_live_sessions")
export class BfrLiveSessions {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: "session_id" })
  sessionId: number;

  @Column({ name: "session_name", length: 100, unique: true })
  sessionName: string;

  @Column({ name: "user_login_id", nullable: true })
  userLoginId: number;

  @Column({ name: "stat_name", length: 20, default: "Login" })
  statName: string;

  @AfterUpdate()
  handleAfterUpdate(): void {
    if (this.statName) {
      const payload = { sessionId: this.sessionId, stat_name: this.statName };
      WebsocketGateway.server.emit('statusUpdate', payload);
  }
 }
}
```

I am getting an error

> Property 'server' does not exist on type 'typeof WebsocketGateway'.ts (2339)

Please help.